# Why I got many NAs when I try to make subset dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have dataset as below

`df<-data.frame(name=c("alicia","samantha","john","jessie"), age=c(40,-23,30,28), income=c(100, 50, 120,60))`

What I am trying to do is to select dataset which does not have negative value and values less than 100.
I've tried

`df[(df[,c(2:3)]>=0&df[,(2:3)]<=100),]`

But I could not delete the values which is greater than 100 and I got many `'NA's`, as below.

```
 #       name age income
 # 1    alicia  40    100
 # 3      john  30    120
 # 4    jessie  28     60
 # NA     <NA>  NA     NA
 # NA.1   <NA>  NA     NA
 # NA.2   <NA>  NA     NA
```

I found the way to delete negative and 100 above values by using `apply` and `subset` functions.

My question is why I got additional lines with `NAs` with my code  `df[(df[,c(2:3)]>=0&df[,(2:3)]<=100),]`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your problem into smaller steps to understand what is happening -

```
#1)
df[,c(2:3)] >= 0

#      age income
#[1,]  TRUE   TRUE
#[2,] FALSE   TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE   TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE   TRUE

#2)
df[,(2:3)] <= 100
#      age income
#[1,] TRUE   TRUE
#[2,] TRUE   TRUE
#[3,] TRUE  FALSE
#[4,] TRUE   TRUE

#3)
df[,c(2:3)] >= 0 & df[,(2:3)] <= 100
#      age income
#[1,]  TRUE   TRUE
#[2,] FALSE   TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  FALSE
#[4,]  TRUE   TRUE
```

Output of 3) is a matrix and now R tries to subset rows where `TRUE` is present which is row numbers

```
which(df[,c(2:3)] >= 0 & df[,(2:3)] <= 100)
#[1] 1 3 4 5 6 8
```

but you have only 4 rows in your dataset so R appends all other rows with greater than 4 with `NA`

```
df[c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8), ]

#       name age income
#1    alicia  40    100
#3      john  30    120
#4    jessie  28     60
#NA     <NA>  NA     NA
#NA.1   <NA>  NA     NA
#NA.2   <NA>  NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `rowSums` in your subsetting to get what you want as in your case you get a matrix to use for substting and not a vector:

```
df[rowSums(df[,c(2:3)]>=0&df[,(2:3)]<=100) == 2,]
#    name age income
#1 alicia  40    100
#4 jessie  28     60
```